# How to use swipeActions with popover in swift ui?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a button that shows after the user swipes left on an `HStack`. When the user clicks on the button, I want to show a popover. However it doesn't work, nothing happens when the button is clicked. Here is my code:

```swift
struct SwipeItem: View {

    @State private var showPopover = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("text")
            Spacer()
        }
        .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
            Button("Modify", action: {
                showPopover = true
            })
            .tint(.green)
            .popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
                Text("popover")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that the popover worked when I moved the `Button` out of `swipeActions` (i.e. directly inside `HStack`). So it seems that `swipeActions` doesn't work with `popover`. What's the problem here? How to make them work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can move `.popover` modifer to set on `HStack`

```
var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Text("text")
        Spacer()
    }
    .popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
        Text("popover")
     }
    .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
        Button("Modify", action: {
            showPopover = true
        })
        .tint(.green)
    }
}
```